# удалить первый элемент из ассоциативного массива

Tags: php

как удалить элемент из массива с ключом data-new

```
array("data-new" => 1,"data-name" => "1","data-balanse" => 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

что бы удалить первый (нулевой) элемент массива, используйте [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php). Данный метод вернет первый элемент, и изменит переданный по ссылке массив. (для удаления с конца используйте `array_pop()`)

```
$first = array_unshift($data)
```

другим вариантом может быть использование [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php), здесь массив будет возвращен, а не изменен.

```
 $new = array_slice($data, 1);
```

для удаления заданного ключа, используйте конструкцию [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php), причем `unset` может принимать сразу несколько аргументов, и в целом применяться не только к ключам массива.

```
unset($data['key'])
unset($data['key1'], $data['key2'])
```

если ключи для удаления у вас находятся в отдельном массиве, можно воспользоваться функций `array_diff_key()`

```
 $remove = ['key1', 'key2'];
 $new = array_diff_key($data, array_flip($remove));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = ["data-new" => 1,"data-name" => "1","data-balanse" => 1];
unset($array['data-new']);
```

Comment: пишет unexpected t_unset

Comment: значит у вас нет ключа "data-new" в массиве, проверьте код который я вам написал, он отрабатывает верно

Comment: вот мой массив, правда уже в json {"data-new":"2","hdate":"1","duedate":"1","rub":"3","eur":"1","debit":"2","credit":"3","balanse":"3"}

Comment: $a = json_decode('{"data-new":"2","hdate":"1","duedate":"1","rub":"3","eur":"1","debit":"2","credit":"3","balanse":"3"}', true);
        unset($a['data-new']);
        print_r($a);

Comment: вот я формирую массив
foreach($array as $value) { 
       $str = array();
       foreach($value as $key => $val) { 
           //if ($key == "data-new")
           $str[$key] = $val;
        }
        if ($str['data-new'] == 2) {
            unset($str['data-new']);
        }
    }