# Как исключить первый элемент из массива foreach

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Как исключить первый элемент из массива?

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
   <div></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Добавить счётчик.

Comment: Если можете, поясните пожалуйста. Если бы я знал - не спрашивал бы...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach($products as $product)  { if ($i > 0) { ?>
<div></div>
<?php } $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

1. [Погуглил за вас](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141108/how-to-find-the-foreach-index).
2. Мой вариант (если это шаблон):

```php
<?php $first_itaration = true; ?>
<?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
  <?php if($first_itaration): ?>
    <?php $first_itaration = false; ?>
    <?php continue; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div></div>
<?endforeach;?>
```

3. [Комментарий](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php#82511) к документации.
4. Документация по [continue](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.continue.php).
5. [Как удалить первый элемент массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836273/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0).

*Я бы не пропускал итерацию, а просто удалял бы первый элемент. Код был бы чище.*

> **UPD** А ещё лучше, не заносил бы не нужные данные.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ.
но вот что выходит: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) in

Comment: А как удалить? Мне нужно его исключить или удалить... технически не знаю как лучше будет...

Comment: @Сергей вы так написали `foreach($products as $product):` ? Не точка с запятой, а **двоеточие**. Так же файл должен иметь расширение `.php`. Правильнее всего - не добавлять в массив не нужные данные.

Comment: это шаблон .tpl opencart. Ваш вариант не подходит. Куча ошибок типа undefined index...

Comment: @Сергей Оформите вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, что это шаблон Opencart

Comment: @Сергей приведите код шаблона. Я не знаю правила написания таких шаблонов, но скорее всего там используется какой-то шаблонизатор.

Comment: Открытие и закрытие массива я написал вначале, внутри html с произвольными ставками php

Comment: @Сергей приведите код шаблона.

Answer (score -1):

Если задача заключаеться именно в том, чтобы исключить первый элемент.

Если вы используете `php` версии 7.3 и выше,
то можно воспользоваться функцией `array_key_first`.

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-first.php

Данная функция получает первый ключ массива.

```
<?php

$array = [...];

$firstKey = array_key_first($array);

unset($array[$firstKey]);
```

Если же, вы пользуетесь версией `php` ниже, чем 7.3,
тогда, можно взять пример полифилла из документации.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('array_key_first'))
{
    function array_key_first(array $arr)
    {
        foreach($arr as $key => $unused)
        {
            return $key;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно использовать функцию [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php), чтобы получить часть массива без первого элемента:

```
<?php foreach (array_slice($products, 1) as $product): ?>
   <div></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php foreach($products as $key => $product) { 
      if($key == 0){continue;}?>
      <div></div>
<?php } ?>`
```

Как вариант. На крайний случай можно добавить счетчик

Comment: Только почему "-1"?

Comment: Почему "-2". Т.е. почему этот вариант плохой? Судя по коду надо пропустить первый шаг, а не исключить первый элемент массива